# Relationships between variables

Tags: python, oop, dictionary

I'm creating a simple game to learn more about OOP. The idea is to have a set of rooms that are lined by cardinal directions, i.e. 'n','sw', etc. I've defined a room class and thought to use dictionaries to keep track of the relationships between the rooms, but this method doesn't work since the values in the dictionary are strings and not the actual variables associated with the locations:

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self,name,exits):
        self.name = name
        self.exits = exits

## Create the "map"
warehouse = Room("warehouse",{'n':'house','w':'pond'})
pond = Room("pond",{'e':'warehouse'})
house = Room("house",{'s':'warehouse'})
```

What's the best way to define the relationship of these Room objects to one another? I know there are modules/tools out there designed specifically for games, but this is more to understand how objects work on a basic level.

Comment: Do the relationships change or will `house` always be north of `warehouse`?

Comment: For something as fundamental as OO programming, I'd be wary of self-teaching. I recommend Head First's series of programming books if you want to get a solid foundation.

Comment: Will check out Head First, always looking for good resources. Not trying to do it all by myslef, though...I'm using Python the Hard Way sort of loosely, and have worked through some other books. @mattm They will be mostly static but some wiggle room would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using room names to make these directional associations, you can keep a dict in the Room class to keep track of which Room instance goes with which name:

```
class Room(object):
    lookup = {}
    def __init__(self,name,exits):
        self.name = name
        self.exits = exits
        Room.lookup[name] = self
```

Add this method to Room so that as you move about, you can get a description from the room of where the exits are.

```
def showExits(self):
    return "This room has %d exits: %s" % (len(self.exits), ','.join(self.exits))
```

This code is fine just like you have it:

```
## Create the "map"
warehouse = Room("warehouse",{'n':'house','w':'pond'})
pond = Room("pond",{'e':'warehouse'})
house = Room("house",{'s':'warehouse'})
```

But now, as each Room instance is created, it also gets saved by name in the class-level dict, `Room.lookup`. Since this is being taken care of for you in the `Room.__init__` method, you really don't need to assign the rooms to variables any more, and could just write:

```
## Create the "map"
Room("warehouse",{'n':'house','w':'pond'})
Room("pond",{'e':'warehouse'})
Room("house",{'s':'warehouse'})
```

Now you can write some simple "walking around" code like this. Note how you get information on each room as you go from one to the next, by accessing attributes and methods on the Room instances.

```
# walk around a while
currentRoom = house  # or Room.lookup['house']
while 1:
    print "You are at the %s" % currentRoom.name
    print currentRoom.showExits()
    command = raw_input("which direction? ").lower()

    if command == 'q':
        break

    if command not in list("nsew"):
        print "that is not a valid direction"
        continue

    if command in currentRoom.exits:
        direction = command
        nextRoomName = currentRoom.exits[direction]
        nextRoom = Room.lookup[nextRoomName]

        # move by setting currentRoom to the nextRoom
        currentRoom = nextRoom

    else:
        print "you can't go that way"
```

Answer (score 2):

As a very naive way of doing this, you could define the concept of `World` into your program and have it track the rooms in a dictionary like so:

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self, name, exits):
        self.name = name
        self.exits = exits


class World(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rooms = {}

    def add_room(self, name, exits):
        self.rooms[name] = Room(name, exits)

    def move_from(self, room_name, exit):
        from_room = self.rooms[room_name]
        to_room = self.rooms[from_room.exits[exit]]

        print("You moved from %s to %s." % (from_room.name, to_room.name))
        # return the destination room.
        return to_room
```

Note that the `World` class provides a helper method to add rooms and keeps track of all of them by name, and then the `move_from` method would take that name, get the room and resolve the exit and print a helpful output before returning the destination room, which then can be used.  An example usage:

```
world = World()
world.add_room("warehouse", {'n': 'house', 'w': 'pond'})
world.add_room("pond", {'e': 'warehouse'})
world.add_room("house", {'s': 'warehouse'})

# Say we start from pond, remember the room that it returns
current_room = world.move_from('pond', 'e')
# then move from the room we remembered from, and see where north goes
next_room = world.move_from(current_room.name, 'n')
```

Running this, we get this output:

```
You moved from pond to warehouse.
You moved from warehouse to house.
```

Of course, this is really naive, there are no error checking so exceptions will be raised if the exits are invalid, and there are no conditional checks at all on the data added, so rooms can be overwritten easily, and also the cardinal directions will not be aligned as you can have a west exit to some other room without a corresponding east exit (or an exit for that matter) back to the former room.  Depending on how you wan to do this, you may want to consider building an `Exit` object to link rooms together so that symmetrical exits are presented, but as you can see the complexity is already increasing.  Still an interesting exercise, but it's probably better for you to find some tutorials to help you with basics of OOP.

Comment: Two excellent answers. I checked Paul McGuire's as it was a little more compact, but both have been highly informative. Apologies for not being able to up vote, as I'm a new user.

Comment: One nice thing about separate World objects is that you can have multiple players wandering independently in separate Worlds.

Comment: I implemented a similar framework to illustrate writing a parser/executor for the commands of such a game, look for "An Interactive Adventure Game Engine Built Using Pyparsing" at http://www.ptmcg.com/geo/python/, which I presented at PyCon '06. Lots of distracting stuff to handle the command parsing, but check out the handling of Rooms and Items, should look similar to what you have started with